# SFML Error: All mentions to SFML(sf::) have undefined reference errors

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm following an SFML/c++ tutorial, and I'm trying to learn c++. I'm pretty sure all the code is correct, but whenever I build it, all mentions of SFML like "sf::Clock clock" and such are errored like so: "undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'"

I'm using SFML 2.1 and Codeblocks 13.12

Is it because I installed SFML wrong? I've tried to install and reinstall it many times, and followed at least 4 video and text tutorials on installation, including the official one. Help is appreciated

Thanks, Flygamer101

Edit: I still cannot find a fix.

Comment: You need to show code so that someone can understand the problem.

Comment: @T.Malo In this case the linker command line would be probably more helpful than the source code.

Comment: I guess @πάνταῥεῖ. I have been tinkering with SFML for about a month now and when I get problems its because of placing something wrong or it comes down to how I linked the dill. So for me if I saw the code snippet I feel I might be able to help. So I should of said can you show code of the problem so that I can better understand the problem you are having. I will get better communicating in the future.

Comment: I've looked at the other answers to the question, and they didn't quite work. It still errors. Here is the Build Log:   http://pastebin.com/3U70SgX7     All of the code is from THIS part of the tutorial: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-a-city-building-game-with-sfml-part-1-state-manager/123